# Bulk import Product Tags to multiple products

Tags: magento-1, import, tags

I've got a list of several configurable products that need product tags added. There are about 15-20 tags per product and close to 50 separate products.
Is there a way to import the tags or run a SQL command to add them?

Comment: I ended up doing it manually since there wasn't a response fast enough.   it was just as easy and fast copy and paste them as a guest user into the product page and then using the admin to panel to approve all pending tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to just use `\Mage_Tag_Model_Api::add`. I never used it, but from reading the code the parameter should be:

```
$data = [
    'customer_id' = 123,
    'product_id' => 321,
    'store' => 1,
    'tag' => [
        'shoe',
        'pullover',
        'elephpant',
    ]
];
```

The alternative is to fill `tag` and `tag_relation` by hand, but I don't know how to do this exactly.

Comment: thanks @fabian b!  Didn't use this as it was as easy and time saving to drop the tags into the product page and approve as it was to create the array.

Answer (score 3):

Tags themselves are saved in the table `tag`, the relation with *products* and *customers* is stored in `tag_relation`.

If you already have the tags created you can run a simple query

```
INSERT INTO `tag_relation` (`tag_id`, `customer_id`, `product_id`, `store_id`, `active`, `created_at`) VALUES
([tag id], null, [product ID], 1, 1, '2015-06-27 15:53:00');
```

And just add a line per product & tag.

If you also need to create the tags in the query it might be a bit more tricky. I would use the Magento `Tag` module and check the save method in `Mage_Adminhtml_TagController` to see what Magento does.

Basically something like this should work (untested so please don't run it on production without testing)

```
$model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
$model->addData(array(
    'name' => '[the name]',
    'status' => 1,
    'base_popularity' => 0,
    'store' => [store_id]
));
$model->setData('tag_assigned_products', array([id of product],[id of product]));

$model->save();
```

In order to add to existing relations (instead of replacing currently assigned products), you need to include them in the array of IDs you specify with `tag_assigned_products`, which you can obtain with `$model->getRelatedProductIds()`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking into an extension such as this one.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-product-tags-easy-tags-bulk-product-tags.html

There may also be open source extensions available that I'm not aware of.